# New 1394B controller not being recognized in VSphere 6.5U3

Tags: esxi

I just added a StarTech PEX1394B3 controller in my standalone ESXi6.5U3 but I cant seems to find what to select to add it to a client on the host.

I have just the free version of ESXi6.5U3 on a Dell R610 with no vCenter.

Within the host PCI Devices it seems to see the card as it shows the following:

```
LSI Coporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller
```

Since the FireWire800 is 1394B I am assuming this is the card. When I try to add the controller to the client I don't see it. All I see is this:

[image: 1394B.png]

In the USB controller there is the 2.0 and 3.0 selection but whatever is selected it does not see the attached devices.

For this card I don't want to use passthrough as I'd have to reboot the host.  But if I have to I will. Is there something I'm missing that needs to be done?  I saw somewhere that there may be a setting in the BIOS that has to be changed.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://virtualguido.blogspot.com/2016/10/vmware-esxi-how-to-find-firmware-and.html?m=1)?

Comment: No I haven’t. Thanks I’ll look it over.

Comment: So I decided to do the passthrough and that was recognized by the client. Only issue now is if I attach it to a Linux VM it shows but fails see the drives that are attached. If on a Windows it works perfectly as the drives show and are accessible.